# Why I can't call keys() on a Typescript Map?

Tags: typescript, variable-types

In a Typescript program (3.9.6), I have a variable p that I believe to be a Map. From console.log(p) I get:

```
Map(2) { 'A' => 0, 'B' => 2}
```

However, it looks like I can't get the keys: console.log(p.keys()) cannot even compile:

```
 error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
 Type 'Number' has no call signatures.
 console.log(p.keys());
```

The variable p seems to come from here:

```
function f(q: IQ){
   ...
   let p=q.data;
   console.log(p);
   console.log(p.keys());
   ...
```

where IQ is defined as

```
export interface IQ {
   data: IData;
}
export interface IData {
     [key: string]: number
}
```

No idea what is wrong, I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is of type `IData`, not `Map` (or at least that is how TypeScript sees it at compile time).

If it is really an `IData` at runtime, use `Object.keys(p)` to get the keys.

If it is really a `Map`, you can cast it like `console.log((p as any as Map<string, number>).keys())`. However, this means that the types are incorrect and it is better to fix the types instead of casting.

Comment: Object.keys(p) gives: [ '$__parent', '$__path', '$__schemaType' ]. And I can access the real keys with p['$__parent]['data']...which seems to me too convoluted. On the other side, casting is not compiling: Type 'IData' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<string, number>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.

Comment: Try `(p as any as Map<string, number>)`.

Comment: oh yes, that's working! thx. I wonder though if the overall solution is "flawed" or not so idiomatic for typescript. Is there a better way of doing creating interfaces and data structure?

Comment: Well yes - it shouldn't be an `IData` at compile time if it is a `Map` at runtime. There's probably something wrong in some other part of the code.